# "Undefined control sequence. \file_get:nnN" error while compiling markdown file to pdf using pandoc and xelatex

Tags: markdown, pandoc, xelatex

I am trying to compile a Markdown file to PDF using pandoc and xelatex.

The command I employed is like this:

`pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex pantest.md -o pantest.pdf`

The error information comes as follows:

```
Error producing PDF.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.931   \file_get:nnN
```

The markdown file I put into test is quite simple:

```
abcdefg
```

It does not contain any CJK characters.

I am using Windows 10, pandoc 2.7 and MikTex 2.9.

---

Following debugging steps suggested by @mb21 in the comment section, the error information seems to have relation with the "unicode-math". Here is the new error I have now:

command used:

```
pandoc pantest.md -s -o pantest.tex
xelatex pantest.tex
```

Error information generated:

```
l.931   \file_get:nnN
                      {unicode-math-table.tex} {} \l__um_mathtable_tl
```

'pdflatex pantest.tex' works fine.

Comment: To debug the PDF creation, it can be useful to look at the intermediate representation: instead of -o test.pdf, use for example -s -o test.tex to output the generated LaTeX. You can then test it with `pdflatex test.tex`.

Comment: @mb21 Thanks for pointing out this!  I followed the debugging steps as you suggested. It turns out that the error information is related to a specific package called "unicode-math". I added details in my original post.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is a problem with the locally installed LaTeX packages. Can you update those and try again?

Comment: I updated my Miktex intsallation today and use Xelatex. I have always the same error message 
`! Undefined control sequence.
l.931 \file_get:nnN`

Comment: I am having the same issue as @FaouziBellalouna. I guess I updated some of my Rstudio packages and the Rmarkdown code that was working before fine, stopped working out of the sudden.

Comment: @R.AndresCastaneda Excuse me but I've forgotten how I solved this problem. I'm really sorry but I searched in my questions and haven't found any thing

Comment: @R.AndresCastaneda If you are using R Markdown, you may give TinyTeX a try, since this issue appears to have affected several people but no one has a solution (and I was unable to reproduce it with MiKTeX): https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1733#issuecomment-564754202

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your LaTeX packages in MiKTeX, [as confirmed by several other users here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1733#issuecomment-582165621). Alternatively, you could try [TinyTeX](https://yihui.org/tinytex/).